# How to find files with same name part in directory using the diff command?

Tags: linux, bash

I have two directories with files in them. Directory A contains a list of photos with numbered endings (e.g. janet1.jpg laura2.jpg) and directory B has the same files except with different numbered endings (e.g. janet41.jpg laura33.jpg). How do I find the files that do not have a corresponding file from directory A and B while ignoring the numbered endings? For example there is a rachael3 in directory A but no rachael\d in directory B. I think there's a way to do with the diff command in bash but I do not see an obvious way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a way to use `diff` for this directly. It will probably be easier to use a sums tool (`md5`, `sha1`, etc.) on both directories and then sort both files based on the first (sum) column and diff/compare those output files.

Alternatively, something like [`findimagedupes`](http://www.jhnc.org/findimagedupes/) (which isn't as simple a comparison as `diff` or a sums check) might be a simpler (and possibly more useful) solution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you know that your files are the same, if they exist and you are sure, there is only one of a kind per directory.

So to `diff` the contents of the directory according to this, you need to get only the relevant parts of the file name ("laura", "janet").

This could be done by simple grepping the appropriate parts from the output of `ls` like this:

```
ls dir1/ | egrep -o '^[a-A]+'
```

Then to compare, let's say `dir1` and `dir2`, you can use:

```
diff <(ls dir1/ | egrep -o '^[a-A]+') <(ls dir2/ | egrep -o '^[a-A]+')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files are simply renamed and otherwise identical, a simple solution to find the missing ones is to use `md5sum` (or `sha` or somesuch) and `uniq`:

```
#!/bin/bash

md5sum A/*.jpg B/*.jpg >index 
awk '{print $1}' <index | sort >sums # delete dir/file

# list unique files (missing from one directory)
uniq -u sums | while read s; do
    grep "$s" index | sed 's/^[a-z0-9]\{32\}  //'
done
```

This fails in the case where a folder contains several copies of the same file renamed (such that the hash matches multiple files in one folder), but that is easily fixed:

```
#!/bin/bash

md5sum A/*.jpg B/*.jpg > index
sed 's/\/.*//' <index | sort >sums # just delete /file

# list unique files (missing from one directory)
uniq sums | awk '{print $1}' |\
uniq -u | while read s junk; do
    grep "$s" index | sed 's/^[a-z0-9]\{32\}  //'
done
```